# comparing milliseconds with data in android

Tags: android, datetime, android-sqlite, milliseconds, android-date

I have `data+time` in saved in database (**`sq lite`**) in **milliseconds**, now I want to get data from sq-lite of a specific date and I have date in this format "**26-December-2012**", how to compare this with **milliseconds**.

what should be the query to fetch data from database?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the milliseconds into date format then compare two dates

convert into date formate

```
        public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{`enter code here`
    // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

    // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date. 
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
     return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

compare dates

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date date1 = curFormater.parse(date1Str); 
Date date2 = curFormater.parse(date2Str); 
if (date1.before(date2)) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new `Calendar` with the timeInMilliseconds data from the database.

So, if you have the time in a column called `date` and the data is in a table called myTable the query to get that is:

```
select date from myTable ... other constraints
```

In android, simply use the long value retrieved from the database to construct a new Calendar:

```
Calendar cal = new Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMsFromDatabase);
```

Once you have a `Calendar` object, you can retrieve the values you want with the [`get(int field)` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29).

Or, you can use the [`DateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful to you

```
    public long getDateLong(String dateString, String format) throws ParseException
    {
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

        Date d = f.parse(dateString);

        return d.getTime();
    }
```

//

```
     long timeMillis; // Your long time millis
     boolean compare = timeMillis > getDateLong("26-December-2012", "dd-MMMM-yyyy");
```